# Python spyder tool clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does `now` and `utcnow` mean in the code suggestions menu in the image below?

[image]

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now and https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow.

Comment: This might help https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Aside, this has nothing to do with Spyder, it’s the built in `datetime` library.

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"explain this code to me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to do the expected research, and then ask about a *specific* point you don't understand..
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
This is a documented feature of your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.now(tz)
```

retrieves the current time.

tz is the timezone specified.

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

returns the time *in UTC*.

> Return the current UTC date and time, with tzinfo None.

> This is like now(), but returns the current UTC date and time, as a naive datetime object.

You could also use

```
datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

---

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now and https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow for more information.

Also, this has nothing to do with spyder.

Comment: Thanks for input.I am clear with datetime.datetime.now function.My question is what does Text denotes in spyder tool?it is string object or something else?I am clear with function,module and class but did not understand Text

Comment: @user3663615 "Text" is just a string of text.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now:

> classmethod datetime.now(tz=None):
>
> Return the current local date and time.
>
> If optional argument tz is None or not specified, this is like
> today(), but, if possible, supplies more precision than can be gotten
> from going through a time.time() timestamp (for example, this may be
> possible on platforms supplying the C gettimeofday() function).
>
> If tz is not None, it must be an instance of a tzinfo subclass, and
> the current date and time are converted to tz’s time zone.
>
> This function is preferred over today() and utcnow().

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow:

> classmethod datetime.utcnow():
>
> Return the current UTC date and time, with tzinfo None.
>
> This is like now(), but returns the current UTC date and time, as a
> naive datetime object. An aware current UTC datetime can be obtained
> by calling datetime.now(timezone.utc). See also now().

Answer (score 0):

As the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) outline, `datetime.datetime.now` returns the current local date and time while `datetime.datetime.utcnow` returns the current UTC date and time.

UTC is simply a fixed timezone that never observes Daylight Savings time. If you want to use UTC timezones with datetime objects, its best to use `datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)`. Again, this is all found in the Python 3 docs.